# Доказувати чи доводити, докази чи доводи: як і коли вживати?

Tags: вживання-слів, дієслова, калька

Згідно з посібником [Культура мови на щодень](http://kultura-movy.wikidot.com/about) обидва дієслова відповідають значенню "підтверджувати істинність чого-небудь", але  "різняться сферами стилістичного вживання". Однак автори зазначають, що "в значенні відповідної предметної дії установився іменник докази".

> **Доводити — Доказувати.**
>
> Слова різняться сферами стилістичного вживання, хоч ще в XIX ст. вони вживалися без стилістичного розподібнення, пор.: *Я стала змагатися, **доводити**, що вона помиляється* (О. Кониський) та *Ти знов тихо і поважно **доказувала** мені, що дрібниці життя мають величезну руйнуючу силу* (Леся Українка). У наведених фразах дієслова мають значення «переконувати кого-небудь у чомусь». У значенні «підтверджувати істинність, правильність чого-небудь фактами, незаперечними доказами» сучасна літературна мова віддає перевагу дієслову *доводити*, напр.: *Наука **доводить**, що життя на Марсі існує, але чи єсть там люди і які вони, поки що невідомо* (Г. Тютюнник).
>
> Отже, для розмовного та художнього стилів властиве паралельне вживання дієслів *доводити*, *доказувати*. Через виразний колорит розмовності, який характерний для вислову *доказувати*, його не приймають діловий, науковий стилі.
> У книжних стилях послуговуються дієсловом *доводити:* *доводити до відома, доводити вину, концепцію, непричетність, право, правоту, теорему* тощо. Характерно, що в значенні відповідної предметної дії усталився іменник *докази*, напр.: *Нюрнберзький процес відзначався винятковою бездоганністю і силою **доказів*** (з газ.); *Один з **доказів** обертання Земні навколо Сонця — існування річного паралакса зір* (з підр.).

Чому ж тоді відомий роман Дж.Остін перекладено, як "Доводи розуму"? Чи не є це калькою з російської мови?

Answer (score 1):

СЛОВНИК УКРАЇНСЬКОЇ МОВИ ONLINE надає такі значення обох слів:

> **ДО́КАЗ, у, ч.** 1. Незаперечний довід або факт, який підтверджує
> істинність чого-небудь; підтвердження. Юзі треба було щодня, щогодини
> доказів приязні від Зоні (Леся Українка); Демонстрація коло воріт –
> найкращий доказ того, що не всім подобається мій приїзд (Я. Качура);
> [Томко:] Товариш Микитюк своєю втечею з тюрми дав нам доказ відваги та
> мужності (Мирослав Ірчан); // *рідко.* Донос на кого-небудь. – І ось на
> саму кутю, як грім з неба, – прийшли [поліцаї ] й забрали [мене]. По
> доказу сільського старости... (Ю. Збанацький).
>
> 2. Предмет або обставина, які свідчать про чию-небудь провину. [Віра:] Що, коли ці папери – єдиний доказ його виновності [винуватості]... і я
>    мушу сама рішати його долю... Жах... (І. Кочерга); Всі докази були
>    проти Явдохи, і ніхто не мав сумніву, що тяжкий злочин – діло її рук
>    (О. Донченко); Їх би за ґрати! Їх би до суду! Їх би до карцеру за
>    розбій! Доказів мало??? Доказом будуть Лантухи вкрадених вір і надій
>    (В. Симоненко).
>
> **ДО́ВІД**, воду, ч. Певне міркування або факт, що наводиться як доказ
> чого-небудь. Тиха Кирилова мова, щира та тепла порада, розсудливі
> доводи не раз спиняли гіркі батькові скорботи (Панас Мирний); Без
> ніякого доводу його обвинувачено в страшному злочинстві, зганьблено,
> закинуто в тюрму, судитимуть і каратимуть його!.. (Б. Грінченко);
> Ніякі доводи про дрібність його пориву, ніякі натяки на важливість
> шляху, з якого він так раптово збочив, не мали більш над ним ні
> найменшої сили (В. Підмогильний).

Оскільки в романі Дж.Остін йдеться не про незаперечні факти, а про міркування, що сприймаються як доказ, то вибір слова ***доводи*** є більш влучним.